Center vertically, but keep top margin when content expands
I have a flexbox with two columns.  The left content is generally taller than the right, and I want to render the right content so that it's centered.
However, the left has content that can expand, and I'd like to keep the right content where it is when it expands instead of staying centered.
So far, I have the first part, but the right part drops to stay centered when the left expands.


.host {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.left-panel {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
}

.summary {
  margin: 5px;
  background: green;
}

.expand-list {
  margin: 5px;
  background: skyblue
}

.right-panel {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: blue;
}

.image {
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}

button {
  margin: auto 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
<div class="host">
  <div class="left-panel">
<div class="summary">
  Here is a long paragraph of text that I need to display.
  It takes up most of the container, but there's an expander
  below that will make this text take up less because the
  expander will take up more when expanded.
</div>
<details class="expand-list">
  <summary>click me</summary>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
  </ul>
</details>
  </div>
<div class="right-panel">
<div class="image">
  <p>
    Don't let this text fool you;
  </p>
  <p>
   it's actually an image.
  </p>
</div>
<button>
  Do it
</button>
  </div>
</div>



I can't explicitly set the top margin on the right content because the left content isn't a set height.
How do I make the right content stay when the left expands?  A CSS-only solution is preferred.

"A CSS-only solution is preferred." - other than positioning .expand-list > ul absolute, I don't see any. (And that will probably have side effects, you don't want.)

To make this work, I had to move the ul expansion panel to after the details element rather than within it, so that it could participate in the containing grid.
The idea here is that the right panel is centered within the first two rows of the grid, while the left panel is 2 rows tall when the details panel is closed and 3 rows tall when the details panel is open.


.host {
  width: 490px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  background: yellow;
  column-gap: 10px;
  &:has([open]) {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  }
}

.left-panel {
  padding: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  &:has([open]) {
    grid-row-end: span 3;
  }
}

.summary {
  background: green;
}

.expand-list {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: skyblue;
}
.expand-list[open] {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.expand-list + ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand-list[open] + ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: calc(1em - 5px);
  display: block;
  background: skyblue;
}

.right-panel {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image {
  background: red;
}

button {
  margin: auto 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
    <div class="host">
      <div class="left-panel">
        <div class="summary">
          Here is a long paragraph of text that I need to display.
          It takes up most of the container, but there's an expander
          below that will make this text take up less because the
          expander will take up more when expanded.
        </div>
        <details class="expand-list">
          <summary>click me</summary>
        </details>
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
          <li>Five</li>
          <li>Six</li>
          <li>Seven</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="image">
          <p>
            Don't let this text fool you;
          </p>
          <p>
            it's actually an image.
          </p>
        </div>
        <button>
          Do it
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>




I'll give this a try, thanks.

Yeah, it's not working in my case.  I actually have two expandable lists under the text, and the right pane can extend into the vertical height of the second list when fully collapsed.  I thought that just having one for the example would be enough, but it doesn't seem so.  You do have a nice solution for the question I asked.

Updated question here if you'd like to give that a go as well. :)
